# Small search bar text - windows explorer

Tags: windows

My aunt just updated her windows 10 pc to the latest update. Her windows explorer search box font size has gone super small, she can barely see the text, it is different from the rest of the font sizes so when she adjusts scale or text size the rest is still bigger.

Anyone know how to reset that, cant see any registry entries for it. Been looking for a c++ method but not sure what dll and libraries I would be looking for.

We have tried safe mode and it was the same, changed themes, etc, so any thoughts would help (don't really want to format, she has a lot of data )

Kind regards